# Why is the API response not being rendered by useState?

Tags: reactjs, api

I am trying to render  data fetched from an API using axios but nothing renders on screen. Note that data is actually available as indicated on the console log. Here is the code and what I have tried.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function Test() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("pulp fiction");
  const [queryFromButtonClick, setQueryFromButtonClick] = useState(
    "pulp fiction"
  );

  const handleClick = () => {
    setQueryFromButtonClick(query);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=fd010aa6&s=${queryFromButtonClick}`)
      .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);

        setMovie(data.Search);
      });
  }, [queryFromButtonClick]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={query}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setQuery(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Fetch movies</button>
      <div>{movie.Title}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

Why are the search query results not being rendered on screen and how can I go on about that?

Comment: Can you share the response of API

Comment: what you have got in api call ?

Comment: you defined movie as array . have you got array in api response ?

Comment: Yes. I iterated over the array as suggested below and hacked it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Movie is defined as an array and apparently data.Search is also an array.
You need to iterate over movie array to get the data about each movie.
Like this:

```
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={query}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setQuery(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Fetch movies</button>
      <div>{movie.map((el)=>el.Title)}</div>
    </div>
  );
```